# How to print on screen 2^20 lines of integers in c++ quickly (under 1 second)?

Tags: c++, output

I have to print on screen  2^20 lines of integers under 1 second printf is not quick enough for there , are there any other easy to use alternatives for fast output?

Each line contains only 1 integer.

I require it for a competitive programming problem whose source code I have  to submit to the judge.

Comment: What do you mean by "print" - show them on screen, output them to a file, maybe even "really" print them out? Which OS?

Comment: Where do you want to print the numbers - console or what? You should to be more specific

Comment: @MarounMaroun & flyx 2^20 is roughly 1 million. If each line is 12 bytes it comes to 12 Mb/s. Could be done on a normal PC.

Comment: @Robert :- To show them on screen. Windows.

Comment: I already wrote 600MB of files with each possible entry with a length of 4, i guess i had 30mins for this on a slow computer but it was long time ago and i did it on java but there was a way.

Comment: What possible reason could you have to output a million lines of integers to the screen, anyway? Does your terminal have enough scrollback to read them? Do you have time to go look at them all?

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov :- console.

Comment: @Wooble :- I need that amount of output for a particular competitive programming problem.

Comment: @AnmolSood: ok... and are the judges of this particular competition going to look at a million integers on your console? This is beginning to sound like an XY Problem.

Comment: Maybe he's building a test parcour for some witty OpenCV computer eye... I can't think of any other needs for this!

Comment: Are those random integers or are you counting up or something?

Comment: @flyx :- not random. ith number is some k*i where k can be determined in constant time for each iteration.

Comment: Another option you could try instead of using an alternative to `printf()` is to use a larger buffer for `printf()`. More buffer size normally means faster. Say you declare `char mybuffer[1000000]`, then you can change the buffer using `setvbuf(stdout, mybuffer, _IOFBF, sizeof(mybuffer))`.

Answer (score 6):

There is [putchar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/) and [puts](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/) that you can try out.

If timing speed of the program is all that is required, you can print out to /dev/null (unix).

Comment: We once had a hexdump contest and that was one of the things we used to get more speed.

Comment: This might help a bit, but I don't think it's going to come close to meeting OP's request... the problem isn't just that `printf` is too slow, it's that terminals don't handle that kind of throughput.

Comment: @Wooble It's for Online Judge so stdout will be redirected and not displayed on a physical terminal.

Answer (score 2):

That's 4 MB of binary integer data. 5 MB if you count the newlines. If you like the data in binary, just write it out to wherever as binary values.

I'll assume you need formatting as well. The best way to do this then is to allocate a "huge" string which is big enough to handle everything, which in this case is 10+1 chars per integer. This means 11 MB. That is a reasonable memory requirement and definitely allocatable on a normal desktop system. Then, use `sprintf` to write the integer values out to the string:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string buffer(11534336, '\0');
  for (int i = 0; i < 1048576; ++i)
  {
    std::sprintf(&buffer[i * (10 + 1)], // take into account the newline
                 "%010d\n", i);
  }

  std::cout << buffer;
}
```

Note the effective formatting operation is very fast.
The physical output to the console window will take some time on Windows, this is inherent to the Windows console and cannot be remedied. As an example, [Coliru times out](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a41edf9c879c7fa4) after 17872 entries, which I believe is 5 seconds. So unfortunately, printing to the screen at this speed is impossible using Standard C(++). You *might* be able to do it faster when you do everything on the GPU directly and display a surface/texture/image you create, but that can hardly be the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

There are about three major bottlenecks in printf

- parsing algorithm (must handle all kind of inputs/outputs)
- base conversions (typically not optimized for your particular purpose)
- I/O

The cure is

- process multiple entries at time
- process file i/o in blocks
- finetune the base conversion for your specific problem

If your numbers are in order, you can have considerable increase of speed by processing multiple integers at a time;
e.g.

```
char strings[10*6];
memcpy(strings, "10000\n10001\n10002\n10003\n10004\n", 30);
memcpy(strings + 30, "10005\n10006\n10007\n10008\n10009\n", 30);

fwrite(strings, 60, 1, stdout);
```

After each block of 10 integers are printed, one has to *update the common part of the string*, which can be done even with 1 x sprintf + 9x memcpy.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what stefaanv mentioned about using `putchar`, this is a somewhat ugly C-style hack that should do the job fairly quickly. It makes use of the fact that ASCII decimal digits are `0x30` to `0x39`:

```
inline void print_int(int val)
{
   char chars[10];   // Max int = 2147483647
   int digits = 0;
   if (val < 0)
   {
      putchar('-');
      val = -val;
   }

   do
   {
      chars[digits++] = ((val % 10) + 0x30);
      val /= 10;
   }while (val && digits < 10);

   while (digits>0)
   {
      putchar(chars[--digits]);
   }
   putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: reminds me of the hexdump contest, even though making hex was slightly easier.